# Displaying text in an animated way!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I want to display a series of text in an animated way one after the other i.e. i want something as displayed in the follwing link..

http://www.tcs.com/homepage/Pages/default.aspx

In the above link a series of text are displayed in animated way and if a user clicks on text a video is opened.i want exactly same feature in my app.

is there any ref or sample code available?

Comment: why the above question is voted down......?

Comment: I have just asked about how to implement such animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you only referring to the text fading and sliding in or do you want the *bubble* animation of the backing image as well? If all you want is the text animation, you can use Core Animation to implicitly animate the text into view by setting the center and opacity of a view--probably a text view. Something like:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[textView setAlpha:1.0f];
[textView setCenter:newCenter];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This code assumes that the current alpha on your text view prior to animating is 0.0 and the center is somewhere off screen. The variable *newCenter* is a CGPoint at which your anchor point will then display after the animation finishes.

Let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: Thanks Matt......but i am not getting what the use of this newCenter.also how to get bubble animation of backing images also.